# Deleted module or framework is still showing in import statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, module, frameworks

I've deleted Example.framework file from Xcode but when i go to code and write import, Example is still showing in the import module list.. Kindly help me how to delete Example from import module list.

things I've tried already..

1. Clean build
2. deleted derived data
3. restarted Xcode
4. restarted system
5. deleted framework files through finder.
6. deleted framework from Project -> General -> Target -> Frameworks and Libraries

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have deleted Example.framework file from Xcode it is from the tree view (on the left of interface) ?

You can check if your target refers to a framework by checking this list :

`Project -> General -> Target -> Frameworks and Libraries`

Comment: Thanks for the help.. but I also deleted the framework from there... I just forgot to mention.